# BAT to remove empty lines, special characters etc from txt

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file to do following:
-remove empty lines
-remove spaces
-remove $ characters
-add 00 after: that misses it
-remove lines that has only 00

What i want is text below

```
142093 
02.05.2016 11: 

142092 
02.05.2016 11: 
$ 142090 
02.05.2016 11: 
142095 
02.05.2016 12: 
142113 
02.05.2016 12: 
142093 
02.05.2016 12: 
142101 
02.05.2016 13: 
142110 
02.05.2016 14: 
142114 
02.05.2016 14: 
142055 
00 
00 
00 
00 
00 
00 
00 
00 
00 
02.05.2016 15:00
```

To look like this

```
142093 
02.05.2016 11:00 
142092 
02.05.2016 11:00 
142090 
02.05.2016 11:00 
142095 
02.05.2016 12:00 
142113 
02.05.2016 12:00 
142093 
02.05.2016 12:00 
142101 
02.05.2016 13:00 
142110 
02.05.2016 14:00 
142114 
02.05.2016 14:00 
142055 
02.05.2016 15:00
```

So far i got this - it removes blank lines, spaces and $ chars but also first line in file which i don`t want.

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set source="C:\Users\Administrator\Pictures\bbb.txt" 
set dest="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\aaa.txt" 

    (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('more +1 %source% ^| find /v ""') do ( 
    set line=%%~a 
    set line=!line:$=! 
    set line=!line: =! 
    echo( !line! 
    )) %dest%
```

Can you help modify this ?

Comment: if you don't want the first line to be removed, why do you explicitely remove it? (`more +1` does this)

Comment: `echo( !line! ` echos _SPACE_ + value `!line!` + _SPACE_ -- do you really want that? you actually have trailing _SPACEs_ in every line of your code...

Answer (score 0):

add the line before echo:

```
set line=!line::=:00!
```